# Update cluster weight on hiding noiseMarkers

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am trying to filter my markers in my Here maps. I managed to hide my Noisemarkers on filter, but the weight of my clusterMarkers are still the same as before.

I was wondering if there is a way in Here maps to get the new weight of clusters after hiding some markers.

My current code is the following for hiding markers:

```
var markerHidden = getCorrectMarker(df.dealersArray[dealerNumberHidden], arrayOfMarkers);
if (markerHidden) {
    markerHidden.setVisibility(false);
}
```

Is there a way to update all clusters on the map with only visible markers or not?

Comment: I have the same issue here, did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Visibility of marker can be set to False only at the map level, however at cluster level, no method defined for limiting the visibility.

Please refer API reference documentation of clustering:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-clustering-intro.html

Comment: Your link now [redirects to here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.30.7/api_reference/index.html). Could you edit your post with a new link to the Clustering Introduction?